# How to resolve 'A get or set accessor expected' compile error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, countdowntimer

Hi I'm trying to write some code that will set a countdown timer in C# but I'm getting a compile error A get or set accessor expected

Looking around it seems that I'm missing some () somewhere, but I'm not really sure where the issue is.

Here's the code that I'm having trouble with, any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
public static class TimeController { 
    static DateTime TimeStarted; 
    static DateTime TotalTime;

    public static void StartCountDown(TimeSpan totalTime)
    {
        TimeStarted = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TotalTime = totalTime;
    }

    public static TimeLeft

        get 
        {
        var result = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeStarted; //THIS IS THE LINE THAT HAS THR ERROR
            if (result.TotalSeconds <= 0)
                return TimeSpan.Zero;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A `{` is missing between `public static TimeLeft` and the `get`.

Comment: This is offtopic as per the rules: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. **This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.**

Comment: It's missing the return type (`TimeSpan`) and a `{`

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you're trying to set `TotalTime`, which is a `DateTime`, to a type of `TimeSpan`, so you need to change `TotalTime`'s type to that of `TimeSpan`.  Next, `TimeLeft`'s type is never declared; so between `static` and `TimeLeft` you should put `TimeSpan` to define its type.  Also, you need to put brackets around the `get` accessor.  All in all, your code should look like this, from what I can tell:

```
public static class TimeController { static DateTime TimeStarted; static TimeSpan TotalTime;

    public static void StartCountDown(TimeSpan totalTime)
    {
        TimeStarted = DateTime.UtcNow;
        TotalTime = totalTime;
    }

    public static TimeSpan TimeLeft
    {
        get
        {
            var result = DateTime.UtcNow - TimeStarted;
            if (result.TotalSeconds <= 0)
                return TimeSpan.Zero;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```